# Trying to identify vintage English bike maker

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

I’m trying to figure out the maker of my great grandmothers bike thanks for any help

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Sunbeam]

I think this answers your question.

Your headbadge is slightly different, probably older.

[image]

See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunbeam_Cycles

Also http://historywebsite.co.uk/Museum/Transport/bicycles/Sunbeam.htm

Comment: How did you find it? Did you know about Sunbeam before?

Comment: @Klaster_1 it's a very famous old manufacturer. The special feature is a fully enclosed chain that runs through an oil bath and ''lasts forever''

Comment: "very famous" among bike connoisseur :) !